# Is this a reasonable proof to conclude that a function is constant if it is $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have function, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Is it sufficient to say this function is constant because a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ involving more than one point will always have jump discontinuities. In addition, because $\mathbb{R}$ is connected at all points, it follows that $f$ must be constant.

I think that it makes sense but I don't know if it is rigorous enough. I have nothing else to say about the proof but was wondering if I was missing something.

Comment: No. You need some assumptions on the function $f$.

Comment: @LouisPan $f(x) = x$ is not a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The standard proof is that continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets. As $\mathbb{R}$ (with the euclidean topology) is connected, also $f(\mathbb{R})$ must be connected. However, in $\mathbb{Z} $ (with the discrete topology) the only connected set are singeltons or the empty set.

Comment: @LouisPan Well $f(1/2) = 1/2$ is not an integer so the range of this function is certainly not contained in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @hunter: Oops... I was thinking about $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb Z$ (the “floor” or “integral  part” function).

Comment: Your post is missing the crucial word "continuous".

Comment: @paulblartmathcop: sure. I was mistakenly thinking about $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: In the case when $f$ is continuous, see [How can I prove that a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is continuous only if $f$ is constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3898099/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted to add that $f$ is continuous (since you’re using that, and since else the statement is not correct). Then that depends on what topology you use on $\mathbb Z$. But the standard topology in $\mathbb R$ induces the discrete topology in $\mathbb Z$. This means that a sequence converges only iff it is constant for all but finitely many $n$.

This follows as for any integer there is a ball that contains only this integer number.

So in that case: Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$ is continuous. Then if $x_n\to x$ we also need $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. This implies that $f(x_n)$ constant for $n$ sufficiently large. Now suppose we have $x$, $y$ with $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Then assume w.l.o.g. that $x<y$. Suppose $x'$ is the supremum of all $x<y$ so that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. The you can find a sequence $x_n\to x'$ with $x_n<y$ and $f(x_n)\neq f(y)$. But since $f(x_n)$ constant for $n$ sufficiently large we get that $x'$ must be in fact a maximum, so there is a largest $x<y$ with $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

But thus for any $z$ with $x<z<y$ we have $f(z)=f(y)$. But this then implies by taking a sequence $z_n\to x$ that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Edit: A different way to do it would be to take $f^{-1}(\{k\})$, which would then be an open set. It is not possible to cover $\mathbb R$ with open sets without intersections. Thus if $f^{-1}(\{k\})$ was something different from $\mathbb R,\emptyset$ we could find some $l\neq k$ so that $f^{-1}(\{k\})\cap f^{-1}(\{l\})\neq\emptyset$. But this would imply $k=l$.

Comment: This is uselessly complicated. In a discrete space the only connected subsets are the singletons. Since the image of a continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a connected subset, you're done.

Comment: @egreg I did not attempt to find the fastest proof to this, but an attempt to formalize the proof the op proposed.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I did need a rigorous proof because I knew that what I had now was not enough. This helps alot.